# $x = \frac{{\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 6 + \sqrt {16} + \sqrt {18} }}{{\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 4 }}$ then $x+\dfrac{1}{x}=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> let :
>   $$x = \frac{{\sqrt 3  + \sqrt 6  + \sqrt {16}  + \sqrt {18} }}{{\sqrt 2  + \sqrt 3  + \sqrt 4 }}$$
>
> then :
>
> $$x+\dfrac{1}{x}=?$$

My try :

$$\sqrt 3  + \sqrt 6  + \sqrt {16}  + \sqrt {18}=\sqrt3+\sqrt 3\times\sqrt2+4+3\sqrt2 \\ \sqrt3(1+\sqrt2+3)+4$$

Now what ?

Comment: what is your Problem here`?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner . how simplify ? $\sqrt 3  + \sqrt 6  + \sqrt {16}  + \sqrt {18} $

Comment: Hint: subtract denominator from numerator. i.e. what is $x-1$?

Comment: Can you try long division?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we say $u = \sqrt 2, v = \sqrt 3$

then 
$\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 4 = u+v + 2$

and $(\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 16 + \sqrt 18) = (v+ uv +  3u + 4) = (uv + 2u+2)+(u+v+2)$

in the first term on the right hand side say $2 = u^2$

$(v + 2u+u^2)+(u+v+2) = u(u+v+2) + (u+v+2) = (u+1)(u+v+2)\\
x = \sqrt 2 +1$

$\frac 1x = \frac 1{1+\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2-1$

$x + \frac 1x = 2\sqrt 2$

Comment: but : $x+1/x= 2\sqrt 2$

Comment: @Almot1960 thanks, I see my mistake and have fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Achille hui's comment expanded:

$$x-1\:=\:\frac{\left(\sqrt 6 +4+3\sqrt 2\right)-\left(\sqrt 2 +2\right)}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+2}\:
=\:\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}+\sqrt 2\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2\cdot2}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+2}\:=\:\sqrt 2 \\[4ex]
\implies\; x=\sqrt 2 +1\quad\implies\;\frac 1x=\sqrt 2-1
$$
which yields
$$x+\frac 1x\;=\;2\sqrt 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
(1+\sqrt2)(2+\sqrt2+\sqrt3)
&=(2+\sqrt2+\sqrt3)+(2\sqrt2+2+\sqrt6)\\\\
&=4+3\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt6\\\\
&=\sqrt{16}+\sqrt{18}+\sqrt3+\sqrt6
\end{align}$$

Thus

$$x={\sqrt3+\sqrt6+\sqrt{16}+\sqrt{18}\over\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt4}={(1+\sqrt2)(2+\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\over\sqrt2+\sqrt3+2}=1+\sqrt2$$

so that

$${1\over x}={1\over1+\sqrt2}={1-\sqrt2\over1-2}=\sqrt2-1$$

and thus

$$x+{1\over x}=2\sqrt2$$

Remark:  The first part of the derivation, starting with the factorization, is, needless to say, presented without all the finagling that went into finding it.

Answer (score 1):

(*Too long for a comment*.)  For a more systematic, albeit grossly overkill in this case, approach:

- with $\,u=\sqrt{2}\,$ and $\,v=\sqrt{3}\,$:

$$
x = \frac{{\sqrt 3  + \sqrt 6  + 4 + 3 \sqrt {2} }}{{\sqrt 2  + \sqrt 3  + 2 }} = \frac{4+ 3u + v + uv}{2+u+v}
$$

- eliminate $u$ by [Resultant[x (2 + u + v) - (4 + 3 u + v + u v), u^2 - 2, u]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+x(2%2Bu%2Bv)+-+(4%2B+3u+%2B+v+%2B+uv),+u%5E2+-+2,+u+%5D):

$$
v^2 x^2 - 2 v^2 x - v^2 + 4 v x^2 - 8 v x - 4 v + 2 x^2 - 4 x - 2
$$

- then $v$ by [Resultant[v^2 x^2 - 2 v^2 x - v^2 + 4 v x^2 - 8 v x - 4 v + 2 x^2 - 4 x - 2, v^2 - 3, v]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+v%5E2+x%5E2+-+2+v%5E2+x+-+v%5E2+%2B+4+v+x%5E2+-+8+v+x+-+4+v+%2B+2+x%5E2+-+4+x+-+2,+v%5E2+-+3,+v+%5D):

$$
-23 x^4 + 92 x^3 - 46 x^2 - 92 x - 23 = -23 (x^2 - 2 x - 1)^2
$$

- then let $y = x + 1/x \iff x^2-xy+1=0\,$, and [Resultant[x^2 - 2 x - 1, x^2 - x y + 1, x]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+x%5E2-2x+-+1,+x%5E2+-+x+y+%2B+1,+x+%5D):

$$
8 - y^2
$$

Therefore $x+1/x=y=\pm \sqrt{8}\,$ and, since $\,x\,$ is known to be positive, $\,x+1/x=+\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}\,$.

Answer (score 0):

simplify the term $$\frac{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{4+3 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}}+\frac{4+3
   \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}}{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\sqrt{16}=4,\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt{2}$$
the final result is $2\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: $\sqrt 3  + \sqrt 6  + \sqrt {16}  + \sqrt {18}=( \sqrt{2}+1) ( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4} )$ 
but. I can not prove

Comment: you must multiply out These terms

Comment: Downvote explained: Insertion of $x$'s value and just printing the final result (known to the OP, cf comment by him) meets IMO the criterion "This answer is not useful."